# comment moderation tool - view full thread not working

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

Comment Moderation Tool on "moderator view", "view full thread" is not working anymore from about two weeks ago. I also try with another browser and device. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's not working at the moment...
After tinkering around, I found a temporary solution to track the original thread/page/post where that comment is made.

Follow Steps:

Go to Moderation View using Chrome.
Right Click on "View Full Thread" then select "Inspect element".
Check the highlighted lines, here you'll see 2 grouped numbers (include the _ underscore).
Right Click the highlighted lines then select "Edit attribute".

Highlight the 2nd group of numbers then copy it (Ctrl + C):
Should look like this: 10150680166299686_32116363_10152029316704686

Open your Comment Moderation Tool in new window.
Replace the ID with the one above.

The public comments should be empty, then click Moderation View.
Here you'll see all comments from that page where the comment was made.
Find a "Visit Website" link then click it to open to new window.

Find the new comment then do what you want. =)